# Trick Windows 7 into downloading a repair disk without an optical drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, system-repair-disc

I have, over time, encountered numerous problems which have caused me to repair/restore Windows 7. I don't have an optical drive installed on my system which causes me various issues including not being able to download the repair disk image. I was wondering if anyone knew a way in which I could use the Windows 7 "Create a System Repair Disk" feature with Windows thinking my USB drive is a DVD drive through some kind of script.

Alternatively, if anyone could provide an alternative method to download a repair ISO. I've tried to go through Microsoft's site and enter my product key, but for whatever reason, it's not valid anymore.

If anyone can help me with this issue, it'd be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could do it manually. I don't have time to write the instructions as an answer, and besides someone has done it already: http://ccm.net/faq/29462-windows-7-create-a-system-repair-usb-key

Comment: Also, you can use original Windows 7 Install Media for recovery. It has all the same recovery/repair and diagnostics tools as a recovery disc does. You can legally download Windows 7 Install media from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried the first method. My BOOTMGR was corrupted so it didn't work. That's why I'm asking for alternative methods. Regarding the download from Microsoft, I already tried that and it didn't recognize my product key as being valid. Literally even mentioned it in the post.

Comment: If you just need a drive you could just instal a virtual one with software like e.g. http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html . If it has to be a RW drive there is also software for that http://www.kernsafe.com/product/totalmounter.aspx. I just googled those two so I have no Idea if it will work or how good they are but they would install a virtual DVD-R(W) drive which Windows should not be able to tell apart from a physical one.

Comment: FYI:  I have had issues with serial numbers for windows in the past.  All that is usually required, at least for me, to read off the serial number and answer a few basic questions.  The representative does their thing, and presto it works again.  I have even done it a few times with the touch tone system.

Answer (score 5):

Just tested Syberdoor's idea and it worked. [KernSafe's TotalMounter](https://www.kernsafe.com/product/totalmounter.aspx) (a free lil tool) did the trick. I got Windows 7 to create a System Repair Disk on file and then copied the files over to USB.

(I formatted the USB drive as NTFS)

Repaired my laptop with it and now I have regained control over my lovely old laptop!